# MySQL JOIN BY to multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I can't get the following query to figured out.

I have 3 tables.

Flags

```
id     flag 
---------------
1      Belgium
2      France
```

**Colors**

```
id    color
---------------
1     Red
2     Yellow
3     Blue
4     Black
5     White
```

**Flag_Colors**

```
id    flag_id  color_id
------------------------
1        1        1
2        1        2
3        1        4
4        2        1
5        2        5
6        2        3
```

I want to get the following result:

```
Flag     Color_1    Color_2    Color_3
----------------------------------------
Belgium  Red        Yellow     Black
France   Red        White      Blue
```

So far I have the following:

```
SELECT 
    f.flag, c.color as color_1
FROM 
    flags f

LEFT JOIN
    flag_colors fc
    ON fc.flag_id = f.id

LEFT JOIN
    colors c
    ON c.id = fc.color_id

GROUP BY f.id
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them directly. you can work around with joins and various if/case statements in the field list, but those get very ugly, very fast. do a standard query and do the row->column conversion in client-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a function though. If you can't use client side code ;)

Here is a solution (which handles **"unlimited" flag colors**)

[**<kbd>The sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b6d3b/1)

**Build the query**

```
create function buildQuery() returns varchar(4000) 
not deterministic 
reads sql data 
begin 
  -- variables
  declare query varchar(4000);
  declare maxcols int;
  declare counter int;

  -- initialize
  set query   = '';
  set maxcols = 0;
  set counter = 0;

  -- get the max amount of columns
  select count(color_id) as maxflagcolors into maxcols 
  from flag_colors 
  group by flag_id 
  order by maxflagcolors desc limit 1;

  -- build the query
  while counter < maxcols do
    set counter = counter + 1;
    set query=concat(query,',replace(substring(substring_index(group_concat(c.color), '','',', counter,'),length(substring_index(group_concat(c.color),'','',', counter,'-1)) + 1),'','','''') as color' ,counter);        
  end while;

  -- return
  return query;
end//
```

---

**Run the query**

```
set @q = buildQuery();

set @q = concat(
'SELECT 
    f.flag ', @q, '
FROM 
    flags f
LEFT JOIN
    flag_colors fc
    ON fc.flag_id = f.id
LEFT JOIN
    colors c
    ON c.id = fc.color_id
GROUP BY f.id');


prepare s from @q;
execute s;
deallocate prepare s;
```

---

**Results**
[image]

[**<kbd>The sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b6d3b/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to output the built query? (so to see 's').

Comment: Sure! Before the `prepare s...` you can do `select @q;`